# What does "builds" mean in Continuous Integration?

Tags: continuous-integration

I see something like "Free for opensource projects or 100 builds per month" but I'm not able to grasp what **builds** means.

Does it mean: The number of tests that were tested/processed?

Comment: The meaning of "builds" in CI is very flexible. Where are you seeing this phrase?

Comment: (Since this was answered and accepted without clarifications, I wonder if it is unclear and thus off-topic. If you can edit it to make the question more substantive, that would be most helpful).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, but requests clarification about a word used in CI.

Comment: @double-beep sorry about that, I hate when I forget this...

Comment: I think the question _could_ be OK, but would need edits to clarify. Presently it could be closed as "Unclear" or "Opinion-based".

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure how I can edit this. Because my only question was what "build" means. It's as you said very flexible and a Software Build is obviously something different than a CI Build. But the answer by Nikos made it clear for me. I thought that other people might be confused as well since there are no google answers for that.

Comment: I suggested earlier that you could indicate where you saw this phrase, e.g. which CI provider. Readers then would be able to say what the word means at that provider, based on their experience of that platform. That is much less "opinion-based" than the question as it stands. (That said, I am not sure the question is worth reopening now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a CI run is triggered (for example because you pushed to your Git repo,) that's a "build".